# Safari - Page not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem where on certain osX & Safari combinations my page refuses to scroll after loading. In order to solve this, I have to zoom in&out on the page or do similar stuff to re-enable vertical scrolling. The code is messy because it all started as a prototype. It may be due to the window size because on a 15" MBP it scrolls immediately while on a almost identical setup 13" MBP is does not.
Here's the link

http://www.cancer3d.org/mainView.php?ensemblID=ENSP00000288602&state=MF

Page takes a while to load the 3d view.
Thank you in advance,
EL

Comment: Looks like when your mouse is hovering over the "3d" object, the page refuses to scroll. Which is because it's loading a canvas, and you can't natively scroll things when your mouse is inside the canvas.

Comment: Probably because the canvas is initializing last. So you'll have to click somewhere else that's not the canvas to scroll.

Comment: Forcing the user to click is bad. Can this be automated / fixed somehow?

Comment: Initialize the canvas first

Comment: It also probably works better on the 15" screen because there's more space, thus it's less likely for your cursor to be over the canvas...

Comment: I tested with the cursor but even if it's outside the problem occurs...